# My switch going to the bathroom light is registering 120 V when the switch is off. When the light is on its at 0 V

Tags: electrical

When I put my multimeter on the wires going to the bathroom lighting, I'm registering zero while the light is on. When I turn the light off it jumps to 120 V. What causes this?

Comment: Are you familiar with what a switch does?  Think it through.  What is the voltage on the neutral side of the lamp? Now when the lamp is off, current is zero but presumably the lamp resistance is smaller than infinity. What is the voltage on the hot side of the lamp when the switch is off?  Is a switch terminal directly connected to the hot side of the lamp?

Comment: Your switch is probably wired to the return (neutral) side of the light.  The hot, from the breaker panel, goes to one side of the light.  And the other side of the light, the return side, goes to the switch.

Comment: @SteveSh: there's no way to infer that from the OP's description; the behavior would be the same regardless of which leg the switch switched.

Comment: sounds like what a switch does.

Comment: @dandavis - That's not correct.  The voltage measured on the light/load side of the switch would be different for those two cases.  When the switch is open, In one case, you would measure the line voltage, ~120 VAC, and in the other case you would measure 0 VAC, or close to it.

Comment: @SteveSh No, you're wrong. It doesn't matter which side of the load the switch is on. When the voltmeter is across the open switch, it's in series with the load.

Comment: You've got either: `Hot--(A)--(infinity ohms)--(B)--(load)--Neutral` or `Hot--(load)--(A)--(infinity ohms)--(B)--Neutral`. Either way the potential difference between A and B is exactly the same. You could tell the difference by testing various points with respect to ground, but not by measuring across the open switch.

Comment: Who said the voltmeter is across the open switch?

Comment: @SteveSh The question title. The title and the question body don't quite agree. The title says he's measuring across the _switch_, while the question body says he's measuring across "the wires going to the bathroom lighting."

Comment: @reirab - Agree that is is somewhat confusing.

Comment: The question does not say that now. it says "going" to the light, which will be one wire. Whilst it is popular in older vehicles to have a "hot" wire going to the load and grounding it to switch on, I would not want that it my home.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Well, here is the *schematic* (as opposed to wiring diagram) of a typical switch circuit.  The light is R1, and that resistance is about right.  VM1 is your voltmeter.

*The switch is open. There is no current moving through the loop. Current is 0.  That's important.*

Can you figure out X volts?  Hint: It's *connected directly by a wire* to 0 volts.

What do we know about Y volts? We know that the voltage across the resistor must be Y - X.   So we can apply Ohm's Law.

```
  Voltage across the resistor = Current x Resistance 

  Y - X = Current x 1200 ohms
```

Can you solve that? Remember, you already know Current and X.  (both zero).

Hint: what is anything times zero?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you are touching the two probes of the meter to the two screws on the switch:

- When the switch is on, the two screws are connected. So all the current for the light flows through a near-perfect conductor (two metal screws plus a very short piece of copper). The meter, which has some resistance, is trying to measure voltage - but most of the current flows through the switch and the meter sees, essentially, nothing = 0V. (I know it is technically more complex, but that is the way I understand it).
- When the switch is off, the two screws are not connected. The hot screw is the equivalent of the hot pin of a receptacle. The switched hot screw is the equivalent of the neutral pin of a receptacle. So when you use the meter you get the same result that you would get by using it on a receptacle - 120V. All the current (which isn't much, a meter is designed so that very little currently actually flows *through* the meter) goes through the meter, so full voltage is registered.

Now this is not *exactly* true. When the switch is off, the switched hot side is not a true neutral, it has a load, as described in Harper's schematic between the switch terminal and the neutral. But the result is nominally the same.

A better test would be to check between hot and ground (ground screw or metal box) and between switched hot and ground. Hot and ground should always show ~ 120V. Switched hot and ground will show 0V when the switch is off but ~ 120V when the switch is on.

Comment: "A better test would be to check between hot and ground (ground screw or metal box) and between switched hot and ground. Hot and ground should always show ~ 120V. Switched hot and ground will show 0V when the switch is off but ~ 120V when the switch is on."  That is only true if the switch is in the HOT (black) leg of the wiring to the light.  If the switch is in the neutral (white)  wire, then there really is no HOT in the box.

Comment: If the switch is on the neutral then therr is a major code violation

Comment: I'm not going to debate that point.  I'm just saying what I think explains OP's observations.

Comment: @SteveSh You can call the wires whatever you want: “hot”, “switched hot”, “return from load”. It doesn’t matter. The OP’s measurements across the switch terminals will be exactly the same whether the switch is on the hot side of the load or the neutral side.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the way I'm interpreting the question.  There are two ways the switch can control the light.  The first is by switching the hot (black) to the light, and the second is by switching the return (white) from the light.

Here a sketch of the first configuration.  The resistor represents the light.

[image]

Here's the second configuration, the one I think the OP has:

[image]

Note that the meter reads different voltages for the open and closed switch configuration between the two configurations.

Comment: I think it's more like the sketch in Harper's answer. Your second sketch is equivalent, but misleading as it has nothing to do with the wire being "hot" or "return". Simply that the voltage is measured over switch and nothing else.

Comment: I don't think moving the switch from the "hot" side to the return side automatically implies moving the measured points from around the lamp to around the switch. You could measure the voltage across the lamp in the configuration of the second schematic too. Or, alternatively, the lamp could be on the other side of the switch even if you measure from around the switch. Now, the post is a bit unclear, in that it says "I put my fluke on the wires going to the bathroom lighting" in one place, and "my switch is registering..." in another, but the result matches the voltage across the switch.

Comment: Please realize that your second diagram is exactly the same as I suggest: the meter is on the two terminals of the switch. You’ve drawn them a distance away from the switch, but that doesn’t matter. Electrically it’s the same thing. And once we agree the meter is across the switch, it doesn’t matter if the switch is on the hot side of the load or the neutral. The readings will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is you are measuring it wrong all voltage on the circuit is relative to ground/neutral so one wire of your meter should be on the "Hot" wire you are measuring and the other on a neutral/white or ground, ground can give spurious results depending on the wiring in the structure.. that should give you a 120 volt reading anywhere on the "Hot" wire up to the load/light unless of course you have a huge "load" on the circuit in which case your reading will be lower see above answers on ohms law.